# Ip camera using ffmpeg drawing on screen

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, ip-camera

I'm using ffmpeg 1.2 to take video from ip camera.I make it draw on the screen, so  I wonder if there is some event mechanism to to know if it is time to call av_read_frame?
If I read frame not so frequent as the camera gives frames i get segmentation fault = on some malloc functions inside ffmpeg routines(video_get_buffer)

I also get segmentation fault just when drawing on screen.

In Render function  call every 0 miliseconds

```
void BasicGLPane::DrawNextFrame()
{
int f=1;
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0)
    {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
        {


            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &FrameFinished,
                                  &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if(FrameFinished)
            {
                f++;
                this->fram->Clear();
               // if (pFrame->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I) wxMessageBox("I cadr");
                if (pFrame->pict_type != AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I)
                printMVMatrix(f, pFrame, pCodecCtx);
                pFrameRGB->linesize[0]= pCodecCtx->width*3; // in case of rgb4  one plane

                sws_scale(swsContext, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                //glGenTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
                if ((*current_Vtex)==VideoTexture) current_Vtex = &VideoTexture2;else current_Vtex = &VideoTexture;
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (*current_Vtex));
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
                glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
                //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
                //glDeleteTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
                GLenum err;
                while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
                {
                    cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << endl;
                }
              //  av_free(buffer);
            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        if (f>1) break;
    }

//av_free(pFrameRGB);
}
```

The picture I get on the screen is strange (green quads and red lines are motion vectors of those quads)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJ9t.png

Answer (score 0):

If you hang on the video device, you should read frames as soon as camera has them; you should either query the camera hardware for supported FPS, or get this information from the codec. If no information is available, you have to guess.

It is suspicious that you get a crash when you don't read the frame in time; the worst which should happen in this case would be a lost frame.

Depending on the camera colorspace you may also need to convert it before showing it on a screen. I don't see you doing that.

Comment: first frame i get is good quality  and normal for viewing , but then step be step the picture transmutate to such a strange thing. I even get crash on zero wait for frame after some minutes working program.

Comment: Is your camera working properly? Could you get the clear good quality video just by using the ffmpeg command-line?

Comment: Yes, ffplay (ffmpeg(libav) 1.2) shows me the normal video from this rtsp stream.

Comment: Just took h264 cam? and have no problems with it, good picture and no crashes. Same code...